# while adding records separately using many-to-one relationship getting variable undefined

Tags: orm, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, fw1

I am using ColdFusion ORM with FW/1.

I have two tables student and parent, I have given many-to-one relationship as we know parent can have more wards in a school. I am adding student and parent separately, while adding parent I need parentId to be stored in student table so that I can list or get student with their parents for further features and activity.

Can anyone help me out how should I save the parent in a parent table and also parentId in student table?

**student.cfc**

```
component output="false" persistent="true" accessors="true" entityname="Student" table="school_student" {


          // Use a mysql autonumber for an ID
          property name="StudentId" column="school_studentid" type=numeric fieldtype="id" generator="identity";
          property name="Fullname" column="school_studentFullname" type="string" length="128" notnull="true";
          property name="email" column="school_studentEmail" type="string" length="128" notnull="true";
          property name="password" column="school_studentPassword" type="string" length="64";

          property name="Parent" fieldtype="many-to-one" cfc="Parent" fkcolumn="student_school_parentId" lazy="true" singularname="Parent"; 
}
```

**parent.cfc**

```
component output="false" accessors="true" persistent="true" entityname="Parent" table="school_parent" {


        //use mysql autonumber id
        property name="parentId" fieldtype="id" column="school_parentid" generator="identity";
        property name="name" type="string" column="school_parentname" length="128"; 
        property name="email" type="string" column="school_parentemail" length="128" ;
        property name="password" type="string" column="school_parentpassword" length="64";


        //relate parent with Student.
        property name="Student" fieldtype="one-to-many" cfc="Student" fkcolumn="student_school_parentId" lazy="extra" inverse="true";
```

This is the way i am saving parent in my controllers:

```
<cfargument name="rc" type="struct" required="true">
<cfset parent = getParentService().parent(arguments.rc.parentid)>
<cfset student = getStudentService().student(arguments.rc.studentId)>
<cfset parent.setName(arguments.rc.name)>
<cfset parent.setEmail(arguments.rc.email)>
<cfset parent.setPassword(arguments.rc.password)>
<cfset getParentService().save(parent)>
<cfset student.addparent(parent)>
<cfset variables.fw.redirect('parent.list')>
```

How can I save parentid in student table while saving parent? I mean how can i call student save method to have parentid in student table?

Any help would be appreciated.

thanks

Comment: If possible, please post some code showing 1.) the ORM config for both entities and 2.) the code you have so far for creating these records.

Comment: I don't know about ORM, but if you were writing your own queries, you would insert the parent record first, then the student record.

Comment: yeah this can be possible if i insert parent record first then student i have to select parent in the form for parentId. but the requirement is first i have to add student then parent.

Comment: Where did the requirment of adding the student first come from?  What if the parent is already in your db because they have another student?

Comment: I agree with you but, at first we insert student then parent.

Comment: Why do you insert the student before the parent?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<cfset parent.addstudent(student)>
<cfset getParentService().save(parent)>
```

And try setting cascade="any" on the student property of Parent. This should allow you to save both objects...even if they are both are new objects being persisted for the first time.

Comment: thanks for your response now its working..i have to setparent in student object to get the parentId in the student table while saving parent.
<cfset student.setparent(parent)>
             <cfset getParentService().save(parent)>